# In the Dirac equation, if the $\alpha$ is the mean velocity, why does it commute with $x,y,z,t$ if the velocity is related to the momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-equation, commutator

In the [Wikipedia talk page for the Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ADirac_equation) I found the following passage:

> The Dirac equation can be proved with the help of the correspondence principle. The energy and momentum of a particle can be expressed by the equation
>   $$
> E^{2}=p_{1}^{2}c^{2}+p_{2}^{2}c^{2}+p_{3}^{2}c^{2}+m^{2}c^{4}
> $$
>   This equation can be divided into {\displaystyle E} E on both sides. We obtain
>   $$
> E={\frac {v_{1}}{c}}p_{1}c+{\frac {v_{2}}{c}}p_{2}c+{\frac {v_{3}}{c}}p_{3}c+{\frac {v_{0}}{c}}m\,c^{2}
> \tag 1
> $$
>   where $v_{0}={\sqrt {c^{2}-v^{2}}}$, and $v^{2}= v_{1}^{2} + v_{2}^{2} + v_{3}^{2}$;
>
> Really ${\frac {p_{1}c}{E}}={\frac {mv_{1}c(c/v_{0})}{mc^{2}(c/v_{0})}}={\frac {v_{1}}{c}}$ and so on, and $ {\frac {mc^{2}}{E}}={\frac {mc^{2}}{mc^{2}(c/v_{0})}}={\frac {v_{0}}{c}}$;
>
> The Dirac equation has the form
>   $$
> i\hbar {\frac {\partial \psi }{\partial t}}=(\alpha _{1}{\hat {p}}_{1}c+\alpha _{2}{\hat {p}}_{2}c+\alpha _{3}{\hat {p}}_{3}c+\alpha _{0}\,m\,c^{2})\psi 
> \tag 2
> $$
>   where $\alpha_{j}$ is matrix $(j=0,1,2,3,)$. We obtain from $(1)$ and $(2)$: $v_{j}/c\rightarrow \alpha _{j}$.
>
> In fact, in quantum mechanics it shows that the relativistic velocity operator $v_{\nu }=dx_{\nu }/dt;(\nu =1,2,3)$ has the form $v_{\nu }=c\alpha _{\nu }$, ie is a matrix operator (see textbook LA Borisoglebsky "Quantum mechanics", Minsk, publishing house "University", 1988, p.340-342).
>
> Really
>   $$
> {\frac {dx_{\nu }}{dt}}={\frac {\partial x_{\nu }}{\partial t}}+[H,x_{\nu }]
> $$
>   where
>   $$
> H=\alpha _{\nu }p_{\nu }c+\alpha _{0}m\,c^{2}
> $$
>   Since the operator $x_{\nu }$ does not depend on time, it will be $dx_{\nu }/dt=[H,x_{\nu }]$. We get
>   $$
> {\frac {dx_{\nu }}{dt}}=[(\alpha _{\mu }p_{\mu }c+\alpha _{0}m\,c^{2}),\,x_{\nu }]
> $$
>   The matrix $\alpha _{\mu }$ commutes with $x_{\nu}$, so that the matrix $\alpha _{\mu }$ can be factored out. Finally we have
>   $$
> dx_{\nu }/dt=c\alpha _{\mu }[p_{\mu },x_{\nu }]=c\alpha _{\mu }\delta _{\mu \nu }=c\alpha _{\nu }
> $$

Why does the $\alpha_\mu$ commute with $x_\nu$? If $\alpha_\mu$ means the velocity,then the Poisson bracket $(v_1,x_1)=\frac{\partial{v_1}}{\partial{p_1}}=\frac{c^2}{E}\neq 0$ and the commutator $[v_1,x_1]=i\hbar(v_1,x_1)\neq 0$.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I have transcribed your images for you; in future please use explicit text entry for anything other than diagrams and similar pictures. (For the specific case of wikipedia, note that copy-pasting the math images will produce working LaTeX.)

Comment: Please take note of the comment at the top of your linked page. The material on this page is seriously misleading with regard to the alpha matrix. It commutes with x because it operates only upon the sponsor coordinates of the wave function.

Comment: That should have read spinor components. DAMN Autocorrect.

Comment: @Lewis Miller  Thanks,I still could not get the key point.

Comment: In classic mechanic,if we regard $v_i$ as a field $v_i(t,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$,
the poisson braket $(v_i,x_i)=\frac{\partial{v_i}}{\partial{p_i}}=\frac{\partial{v_i}}{\partial{x_i}}\frac{\partial{x_i}}{\partial{p_i}}+\frac{\partial{v_i}}{\partial{t}}\frac{\partial{t}}{\partial{p_i}}=0$, so the velocity and position commute. I do not know how to explain this......

Comment: $\alpha_\nu$ is not the velocity, it is a matrix, that acts on the components of the wave-function (and not on its spacial part).

Comment: @Adam But the wiki say,velocity operator $v_i=c\alpha_i$

Comment: In QM, the velocity operator is usually *defined* as $d \hat x/dt$.

Comment: @Adam  Is there anything wrong with the wiki?The wiki said here $d\hat{x}_i/{dt}=c\alpha_i$

Comment: That might be fine. It does not mean that $\alpha_i$ does not commute with $\hat x_i$. As I said, the definition of the velocity operator is $d\hat_i/dy$. It so happens that in your case, $[\hat H,\hat x_i]=x\alpha_i$

Answer (score 1):

You say the velocity is related to the momentum. What you probably have in mind is the classical relation
$$
\mathbf{P}=m\mathbf{V}
$$
This relation does not hold true in quantum mechanics. Velocity and momentum are not proportional operators. Therefore there is not contradiction between
$$
[\mathbf{V}_j,\mathbf{X}_k]=0 \quad \quad \textrm{and} \quad \quad [\mathbf{P}_j,\mathbf{X}_k]=-ih\delta_{jk}
$$

@Adam pointed this out implicitly.

Comment: That sounds strange: in low-velocity limit, where the Schrödinger's equation should work fine, for a free particle we have velocity $\hat V_j=\frac i\hbar [\hat H,\hat X_j]$, which reduces to $\hat P_j/m$ for the free particle non-relativistic Hamiltonian. And _this_ doesn't commute with $X_j$. There's no way how a zero commutator could become nonzero in any limit. What is wrong in my reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

```
It’s important to understand what the “Dirac wave function" represents. An electron of momentum $p$ with spin +1/2 in the $z$-direction is represented by the quantum state
```

$$|p,\uparrow\rangle\quad.$$
A general state of momentum $p$ will be represented as a superposition
$$c_1 |p,\uparrow\rangle + c_2 |p,\downarrow\rangle$$
which can be packaged nicely into a spinor
$$\chi(p) = \begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\end{pmatrix}\quad.$$
Under Lorentz transformations, the momentum will change, but the spinor will also rotate. This transformation is not very nice. The solution is to multiply this spinor by a boost matrix:
$$\psi^\alpha(p) = (\sqrt{p\cdot \sigma})^{\alpha}{}_{\alpha'}\,\chi^{\alpha'}(p)\quad.$$
The new spinor $\psi(p)$ transforms nicely under Lorentz transformations $\Lambda^\alpha{}_{\alpha'}$, and inverting the boost:
$$(\sqrt{\Lambda p\cdot \sigma}\;{}^{-1})^{\alpha}{}_{\beta}\,\Lambda^{\beta}{}_{\beta'}(\sqrt{p\cdot \sigma})^{\beta'}{}_{\alpha'}=R{}\,^{\alpha}{}_{\alpha'}$$
gives precisely the needed rotation of the spinor. This construction is not unique. We can also construct a spinor in the conjugate representation of the Lorentz group:
$$\widetilde\psi^\alpha(p) = (\sqrt{p\cdot \bar\sigma}\,)^{\alpha}{}_{\alpha'}\,\chi^{\alpha'}(p)\quad$$
so that now $\widetilde \psi$ transforms under $\Lambda\!{}^*{}^\alpha{}_{\alpha'}$. These spinors satisfy
$$p\cdot \bar\sigma \,\psi(p) = m \,\widetilde\psi(p)\quad.$$
We can Fourier transform to position space, where the equation will read
$$\bar\sigma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi(x)= m\widetilde \psi(x)\quad.$$
These wavefunctions are more conveniently packaged into a single wave function
$$\Psi(x) = \begin{pmatrix}\psi(x)\\\widetilde{\psi}(x)\end{pmatrix}$$
that now satisfies the Dirac equation
$$\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \Psi(x) = m\, \Psi(x)\quad.$$
But now remember that $\Psi(x)$ is just a convenient way of packaging the coefficients $\chi(p)$ and is not a quantum state at all. Thus, the matrices $\gamma^\mu$ commute with $X$ because they are not quantum operators.